# New JavaScript object instance unexpectedly retaining old array data

Tags: javascript, arrays, instance, retain, persist

I have a JavaScript object declared in code like:

```
ObjectClass = Class.extend({
    ...
    arrayProperty : [],
});
```

It gets instantiated with:

```
var gblObject;
...
gblObject = new ObjectClass();
```

`gblObject.arrayProperty` always gets an initial value written to is using `gblObject.arrayProperty.push(defaultObject);` and potentially gets more values written to it, but using `gblObject.arrayProperty = [defaultObject, anotherObject, ..., nObjects];` Note: `defaultObject` is the same object that was added initially using `push`.

Eventually `gblObject` gets reset with `gblObject = null;`

The issue comes in when I try to use the same namespace `gblObject = new ObjectClass();`. When I do this, I can console log and see that `gblObject.arrayProperty` returns `Array [ {defaultObject} ]`. I expect this to be an empty array however, since it's a completely new instance of `ObjectClass`. The weird thing is `gblObject` looks empty in the console log: `Object { }`. But there's a `<prototype>` value on the empty object, and this contains that pesky `arrayProperty : Array [ {defaultObject} ]` assignment.

Why would the object property array value persist on new instances, but only the value that gets written using `push`?

I was able to workaround the persisting value by setting the initial array value with `gblObject.propertyAsList = [defaultObject]` instead of using `push`. Another solution was to do:

```
gblObject = new ObjectClass();
gblObject.arrayProperty = [];
...
gblObject.arrayProperty.push(defaultObject);
```

But I would still like to understand why this issue occurs.

Comment: Why would you expect the array on the new instance to be empty? You explicitly modify the array on the prototype, which is where the instance inherits the property. Nothing about JavaScript inheritance says that a new instance gets new "clean" properties.